# mysql cast alias into an integer datatype

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have made a leaderboard in my game using mysql to store user details and score. Now I want to retrieve rank of the user based on his details. I am getting result if I use query as suggested on this site [rank query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table).

But it has a problem. The rank alias is of type tinyint and it gives ranks only upto 255 after that it simply returns rank as 0. I want to type cast it to an integer so that that query will be able to return rank of much higher values. I used CAST but it gives error.

this is the query that returns the rank 'code':

```
SELECT id, name, score, 
       FIND_IN_SET(score,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                          FROM scores ) ) AS rank 
FROM scores 
WHERE name = 'Assem'
```

Please help on this matter.
Thanks

I tried to type cast it as

```
SELECT name, FIND_IN_SET( score, (    
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
        ORDER BY score DESC ) 
        FROM hiscores )
        ) AS CAST(rank as UNSIGNED)
        FROM hiscores
        WHERE phone = '$phone'
        ;
```

and

```
SELECT name, CAST (FIND_IN_SET( score, (    
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
        ORDER BY score DESC ) 
        FROM hiscores )
        ) as UNSIGNED) AS rank
        FROM hiscores
        WHERE phone = '$phone'
        ;
```

But both are giving errors

Comment: this is the query that returns the rank 'SELECT id, name, score, FIND_IN_SET( score, (    
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
ORDER BY score DESC ) 
FROM scores )
) AS rank
FROM scores
WHERE name =  'Assem''

Comment: What column type is your score column?

Comment: its of type signed int